# Using a Circular Progress Indicator with Firebase Animated List in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I want to show a circular progress indicator on my screen until the data is fetched from the database which I am showing using FirebaseAnimatedList. But there is no way to check if the data is available yet. e.g. In FutureBuilder, there is a method hasData. Is there anything similar in FirebaseAnimatedList?

Comment: is it an asynchronous call?

Answer (score 1):

Use defaultChild: in firebaseAnimatedList for creating default screen while the query gets loaded

Comment: Prefect!, Thanks alot :)

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you can work with exists() from DataSnapshot.

```
itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, DataSnapshot snapshot,
                  Animation<double> animation, int index) {

     if(!snapshot.exists()) {
        // return fancy loading stuff
     }
}
```

Comment: I am getting an error. exists() method doesn't exist for DataSnapshot.

Answer (score 0):

**Put CircularProgressIndicator() in defaultChild property of FirebaseAnimatedList.**

```
   FirebaseAnimatedList(
    defaultChild:Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
    query:databaseReference,
   itemBuilder(context, DataSnapshot snapshot,
   Animation<double> animation, int index) {
   return Text('''')})
```

Answer (score 0):

Their is one Property called `defaultChild` in `FirebaseAnimatedList` which will consider executing until data is getting loaded from `snap shot` or is still `waiting` and `loading` to fetch data.

To apply that just write for e.g you want to show Loader until that.

```
defaultChild: const Center(
    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
),
```

Inside `FirebaseAnimatedList` and you will see a loader until data is not `fetched`.